# setting initial variable for base class from inherited class

Tags: class, visual-c++

I am a little rusty with C++ and am getting bogged down with what is probably a simple question, so apologies in advance.

I have created a child class from an existing library class and cannot work out how to set up an initial state for one of the base class functions.

Basically I have taken the sfml circleshape class and added a little of my own, but I would like to set the origin for all derived objects as a fixed number.

The base class takes 'name of class'.setOrigin(x,y) which is straightforward, but I want to know how to set this as a standard figure in all derived class instances. (basically my child class is called Ball and I have class Ball ball1, ball2 etc

This may make it clear what I have at the moment:

```
//derived class-----------------------------------------
```

class Ball : public sf::CircleShape
{
private:
    int horiz,vert,rate,radius;
public:

```
void setHoriz(int hin)
{
    horiz=hin;
}
int getHoriz(int hout)
{
    hout=horiz;
    return(hout);
}
void setVert(int vin)
{
    vert=vin;
}
int getVert(int vout)
{
    vout=vert;
    return(vout);
}
//-----------------------------------------------
void setRate(int in)
{
    rate=in;
}
int getRate(int out)
{
    out=rate;
    return(out);
}
//-----------------------------------------
```

};
So any advice on how to insert ' CircleShape.setOrigin ' into the Ball class would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If I understand the issue, all you want is to call `setOrigin` in `Ball`'s constructor: `Ball() { setOrigin(0, 0); }`

Comment: Thanks Igor. I dont think I explained myself very well. What I am trying to do is to call an instance of class Ball where it is automatically set with the origin in the centre, rather than at top left of the bounding box which is the default of the parent (base) class.. e.g I want to create instances of class Ball (ball1, ball2 etc) which have already got the origin set to the centre as a default (and maybe also set a default radius as well)

Comment: How is an instance of `Ball` expected to know the size of the bounding box, and the value of radius that you would consider "default"? The latter, I suppose, could be hard-coded in the constructor: `Ball() : radius(42) {}`